# JavaFX-StackedBarChart with groups

Tags: java, javafx, charts, stacked-chart

I want to create a `StackedBarChart` with groups, but I could not find any way to do it. What I have is like that:

```
public class TestStackedBarChart extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Group root = new Group();

    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    xAxis.setLabel("Month");
    xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.<String> observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(
            "January", 
            "February",
            "March")));
    yAxis.setLabel("Value");

    final StackedBarChart<String,Number> stackedBarChart = new StackedBarChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
    stackedBarChart.setTitle("StackedBarChart");

    XYChart.Series<String,Number> series1 = new Series<>();
    series1.setName("XYChart.Series 1");       

    series1.getData().add(new Data<String, Number>("January", Integer.valueOf(100)));
    series1.getData().add(new Data<String, Number>("February", Integer.valueOf(200)));
    series1.getData().add(new Data<String, Number>("March", Integer.valueOf(50)));

    XYChart.Series<String,Number> series2 = new Series<>();
    series2.setName("XYChart.Series 2");

    series2.getData().add(new Data<String, Number>("January", Integer.valueOf(150)));
    series2.getData().add(new Data<String, Number>("February", Integer.valueOf(100)));
    series2.getData().add(new Data<String, Number>("March", Integer.valueOf(60)));

    stackedBarChart.getData().add(series1);
    stackedBarChart.getData().add(series2);

    root.getChildren().addAll(stackedBarChart);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

And that's the result:

[image: StackedBarChart (Actual)]

What I want to have is something like that:

[image: StackedBarChart (Target)]

Is there any way to do it in JavaFx? You could also suggest any other Chart-Type but the solution should be with JavaFX.

Comment: Unless im mistaken, XYChart.series is an extends from Region, which means it should have a padding. To create the multiple bars per Month have a look at [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm). Note i have not BarCharts alot, just for a small graph so i might be wrong. But the solution would be to follow the example from oracle and then remove the padding from the bars where you want no whitespace.

Comment: @namlik I think you have misinterpreted what I am looking for. I am looking for a solution to group the elements, for example Product1,2,3->Grouped in January. Padding has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: Well doesn't the link show an example of this being done? the first example groups the bars by country. Might have looked over it cause of the wall of text, normally if you combine the methods and examples given there you should be able to reach a solution you are happy with here --> [KLIK HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm)

Comment: @namlik I have seen this link. But there is no example of this being done.

Comment: i have to apologize, i thought it was possible to nest the charts, hereby creating the result you wanted. After testing and trying to build an example i have not found a way to do what i thought being possible. This feature seems to be lacking in javafx as i cannot find an example of it being done anywhere. Perhaps other people can help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with the stacked bar chart for a while, I have found a solution acceptable for me. It was not possible to group the stacked bar nodes, but it was possible to sort them in a way that the grouped entries stay side by side. Here is the result:

[image: StackedBarChart with sorting]

And here is how I did it:

```
public class TestStackedBarChart extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Group root = new Group();

    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    xAxis.setLabel("Month");
    xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.<String> observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(
            "January(Plan)", 
            "January(Actual)",
            "February(Plan)",
            "February(Actual)",
            "March(Plan)",
            "March(Actual)")));
    yAxis.setLabel("Value");


    final StackedBarChart<String,Number> stackedBarChart = new StackedBarChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
    stackedBarChart.setTitle("StackedBarChart");        

    XYChart.Series<String,Number> series1 = new Series<>();
    series1.setName("Category A");
    series1.getData().add(new Data<>("January(Plan)", Integer.valueOf(100)));
    series1.getData().add(new Data<>("February(Plan)", Integer.valueOf(200)));
    series1.getData().add(new Data<>("March(Plan)", Integer.valueOf(50)));

    XYChart.Series<String,Number> series2 = new Series<>();
    series2.setName("Category B");  
    series2.getData().add(new Data<>("January(Plan)", Integer.valueOf(200)));
    series2.getData().add(new Data<>("February(Plan)", Integer.valueOf(100)));
    series2.getData().add(new Data<>("March(Plan)", Integer.valueOf(25)));        

    XYChart.Series<String,Number> series3 = new Series<>();
    series3.setName("Actual Value");           
    series3.getData().add(new Data<String, Number>("January(Actual)", Integer.valueOf(250)));
    series3.getData().add(new Data<String, Number>("February(Actual)", Integer.valueOf(275)));
    series3.getData().add(new Data<String, Number>("March(Actual)", Integer.valueOf(60)));

    stackedBarChart.getData().add(series1);
    stackedBarChart.getData().add(series2);
    stackedBarChart.getData().add(series3);

    root.getChildren().addAll(stackedBarChart);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```